# MongoDB document model code value type data in C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, model, keyvaluepair

I have a relational table that stores **key-value** data in the below structure.

```
KEY        VARCHAR(10)
Value-Text VARCHAR(50)
Value-Date DATETIME
Value      NUMERIC
```

So for any given key, there will be only one Value column used.  This is not a good design in first place.  If I have to create a similar key-value pair in mongo where the value field have different data types, what is the best option ? How will it work with the **C#** driver ?

Comment: In mongo you need not to specify any data type for the `value`

Comment: Thanks gypsyCoder.  How will the C# driver serialize it.. that was my question - as Object

Comment: avoid strictly type... you can use 'var'

Answer (score 0):

As gypsyCoder mentioned, there is no need to store the type as part of the schema.  In C#, you can define `value` as an `object` in your POCO, and the driver will serialize the value as the underlying type.  There are a few exceptions.  For example, MongoDB does not support decimal types, so decimals are serialized as strings. However, most primitives will translate between C# and MongoDB nicely.